# Problem with bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

I'm using

```
@electronic{something,
title           = {something else,
author          = {Hu, Xiao.-Yu},
url             ={http://www.sth.sth.sth.sth.sth/sth/LEK_ECC.html}}
```

in my bibliography.bib file. Then in my .tex file I have:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}    
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\cite{something}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The problem is with the name of the author printed as "X.-Y." and for the url I get LEK ECC.html without the underline inbetween. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the author as

```
author = {Hu, Xiao{-}Yu},
```

so the hyphen will be hidden and not mistaken for a compound name marker à la French (Jean-Claude or similar).

For the URL, load also `\usepackage{url}`.

Example (with `filecontents*` just to make it selfcontained, use your separate file).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@electronic{something,
  title  = {something else},
  author = {Hu, Xiao{-}Yu},
  url    = {http://www.sth.sth.sth.sth.sth/sth/LEK_ECC.html},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{something}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Elnaz What should it be?